# app/uninstalled webhook not fired in C# controller or NGROK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, shopify, webhooks

I have subscribed to a webhook for when a user in a Shopify store deletes the application:
The idea is that I can catch the endpoint with a breakpoint or see the output of the logger. Nothing did do it for me yet.

```
{
    "webhook": {
        "id": 1162744922297,
        "address": "https://2aa0-94-168-221-206.ngrok-free.app/Home/Uninstalled",
        "topic": "app/uninstalled",
        "created_at": "2023-09-12T16:19:54+02:00",
        "updated_at": "2023-09-12T16:19:54+02:00",
        "format": "json",
        "fields": [
            "id"
        ],
        "metafield_namespaces": [],
        "api_version": "2023-04",
        "private_metafield_namespaces": [
            "Appname-test"
        ]
    }
}
```

But In my HomeController in C# nothing happens when I actually delete the app:
The controller is not fired at all. I use NGROK for exposing localhost and also there I don't see an incoming request

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Uninstalled()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Webhook Uninstalled fired");
            return Ok("uninstalled");
          
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what I need to do to fire that Controller endpoint so that I can do stuff when a user deletes the app

I tried different naming, but nothing did do it for me yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter to the method for it being able to get fired

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).